# Choosing a weighted task in O(1) space-time complexity

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, time-complexity

Suppose I have a list **L** of tasks. Each task is represented by an integer weight, which states how important the task is.

The importance of a task doesn't affect its order, but affects its chance of being chosen. For example: if I have 2 tasks A and B of weights 3 and 1, A will have 75% of chance of being chosen, while B has 25%.

How can I have a constant-time/space algorithm that chooses a random task from a list of tasks taking their weights in consideration?

---

My current solution is choosing a random number between 0 and the sum of all elements in **L**. Then I iterate through **L** like this:

```
int random = RandomInInterval(0, sumOfL);
foreach(Task T in L){
    random -= T;
    if(random <= 0) return T;
}
```

This is constant in space but linear in time. Is there a way of making a time-constant solution?

Once I set **L**, it will not change, so the complexity of evaluating the sum of the weights can be ignored, because I will only evaluate it once. On the other hand, I'll be choosing Tasks all the time.

Comment: If L is constant, then you could calculate once the sum of weights to ith task, then use binary search (O(log(n))) to find your random task rather than linear search (O(n)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constant time will require a lookup table.  You can use this to optimize the procedure you already have.

- divide the range from 0 to `sumOfL` into equal-sized regions that are small enough so that each region overlaps the ranges for at most 2 tasks.  Making the region size smaller than the smallest task range will ensure this.
- Make an array of regions that records, for each region, either single task that it corresponds to, or the two tasks and the dividing line between them.

Now you can select a region in constant time:

- generate a random number in `[0, sumOfL)`
- divide by the region size and index in the array to find the region
- test the random number against the region's dividing line if necessary to determine which of the two tasks to select.

Comment: Seems like it is impossible to have O(1) space complexity...

Answer (score 0):

I've written a library for exactly this: https://github.com/cdanek/KaimiraWeightedList

If you want to roll your own, you need to get a little fancy. Start by reading up on the [Alias Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method) and looking at [Keith Schwartz's explanation](https://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/) (this is really good).

You won't be able to get O(1) space complexity, unfortunately. O(N), yes, O(1), no. O(1) processing complexity for your use-case (gets) is possible, though.